# How to draw a boxplot with only chosen columns using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I have an iris dataset that has 5 columns,4 of which are useful features and I wanna draw a boxplot using them,but I also have a useless column that I wanna drop out,how can I do it?
[columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ0nk.png)
The code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris_data = load_iris()
# print(iris_data)
iris = pd.DataFrame(data=np.c_[iris_data['data'], iris_data['target']],
                    columns=iris_data['feature_names'] + ['species'])
setosa = iris.head(50)
print(setosa.columns)
plt.boxplot(setosa, vert=True)

plt.show()
```

I expect a boxplot only has the first four features

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not a picture. This can help one to reproduce the issue and resolve the problem. Regarding your question, also mention the column to be dropped and the column required as a feature.

Comment: You can use `setosa.iloc[:, :4]` to select the first 4 columns of your dataframe. If you want to learn more about selecting data from pandas dataframes, you can read user guide on [selecting and indexing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column can be dropped using `DataFrame.drop(columns='<your_column_name>')`. More information can be found in the documentation of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris_data = load_iris()

iris = pd.DataFrame(data=np.c_[iris_data['data'], iris_data['target']],
                    columns=iris_data['feature_names'] + ['species'])
iris = iris.drop(columns="species")
setosa = iris.head(50)
print(setosa.columns)
plt.boxplot(setosa, vert=True)

plt.show()
```